# WebStorm can't autocomplete styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, webstorm, styled-components

I'm developing a React project in WebStorm, but I'm having a problem due to the structure I've set up.

Normally, WebStorm supports styled-components, autocomplete works fine, but the standard way to access the theme object I provide from ThemeProvider results in a very dirty piece of code.

[image]

To get cleaner code, I used an alternative way to send a function to styled-components and capture variables from the theme object as arguments, but that way WebStorm doesn't autocomplete.

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You might want to add relevant code into the question instead of just pictures of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you gave to the styled-component should return the "css" object that you will import from the styled-components library as named import.

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

const Button = styled.button(({ theme, size, type }) => css`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  background-color: ${theme.paper};
  color: ${theme.brand};
  font: ${theme.medium16};
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: solid 0.8px ${theme.brand};
  cursor: pointer;
`);
```

[image]